# Laravel Nova - preselect null option

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a field in one of Nova actions that can have both null and int values:

```
public function fields(NovaRequest $request): array
{
    /** @var Account $account */
    $account = $request->findModelQuery()->first();

    return [
        Select::make('Usage limit')
            ->options([
                10 => '10',
                100 => '100',
                500 => '500',
                1000 => '1000',
                2500 => '2500',
                5000 => '5000',
                8000 => '8000',
                null => 'Unlimited',
            ])->default(function ($request) use ($account) {
                return $account->getFeatureLimit($this->featureName);
            }),
    ];
}
```

`$account->getFeatureLimit($this->featureName)` returns pre-existing value that can be `?int`

Value is pre-selected when number is returned, however, when pre-existing value is `null`, `Unlimited` is not selected:
[image]

Is there any way in Laravel Nova to preselect null => Unlimited?
Tried `withMeta` method in combination with `nullable()` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem when you try to set a value of an option field as null. I just tested it out and it renders without a value:

```
<option value>Unlimited</option>
```

I would change the key of unlimited to be another non null value and then just check if `getFeatureLimit` returns null. If it does just return the new key for `Unlimited`. With the method `fillUsing` you can dictate how you want to hydrate the model attribute like this:

```
Select::make('Usage limit')
            ->options([
                10 => '10',
                100 => '100',
                500 => '500',
                1000 => '1000',
                2500 => '2500',
                5000 => '5000',
                8000 => '8000',
                'unlimited' => 'Unlimited',
            ])->default(function ($request) {
                $default = null;

                if (! is_null($default)) {
                    return $default;
                }

                return 'unlimited';
            })->fillUsing(function (NovaRequest $request, $model, $attribute, $requestAttribute) {
                $value = $request->usage_limit;

                if ($value === 'unlimited') {
                    $value = null;
                }

                $model->usage_limit = $value;
            }),
```